# Existing rows in join table not being cleared during many-to-many update

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In the simplest terms, when I try to update my object, `Activities`, from POST data, the existing many-to-many join data for the relationship `Activities.Contacts` does not get removed from the MSSQL DB during `SaveChanges`.  This results in an error if one of the Contacts in the POST data already exists for that Activity.

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tblActionContact'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tblActionContact'. The duplicate key value is (1, 94)

My controller for this:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(Activity activity)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //save the activity
            activity.Contact.Clear(); //Clear the existing contacts
            db.Entry(activity).State = EntityState.Modified;

            //then add each contact
            foreach (int contactId in activity.SelectedContactIds)
            {
                activity.Contact.Add(db.tblContact.Find(contactId));
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["Flash Success"] = "Activity Saved";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return View(activity);
    }
```

I have tried oh so many different variations based on much searching of this fine site, but I have found nothing that will work.

I had very high hopes for `activity.Contact.Clear()` and that does indeed clear the existing Contacts from the Activities in the object, but it does not clear them from the actual MSSQL table.

If I am selecting novel contacts that were not selected in the existing `Activity`, then it saves fine, including of course when creating a new `Activity`.

Please, I am new to posting here so please let me know if more code or info is needed!

**Edit**
I am posting my context and applicable models:

Context:

```
public partial class SalesEntities : DbContext
{
    public SalesEntities()
        : base("name=SalesEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<SalesAccount> tblAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Activity> tblAction { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ActionTypeLookup> tblActionTypeLookup { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Campaign> tblCampaign { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Contact> tblContact { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<GenericLookup> tblGenericLookup { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<MarketingLetter> tblMarketingLetter { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Opportunity> tblOpportunity { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Product> tblProduct { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Source> tblSource { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<VerifiedAccount> tblVerifiedAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
}
}
```

And the Activity model:

```
namespace SalesTracker.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Activity
{
    public Activity()
    {
        this.Contact = new HashSet<Contact>();
    }

    public int ActionId { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public int CampaignId { get; set; }
    public string SalespersonId { get; set; }
    public int ActionTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ActionDate { get; set; }
    public string NextStep { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> MarketingLetterId { get; set; }
    public string EditedBy { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime EditDate { get; set; }
    public bool Completed { get; set; }

    public virtual SalesAccount SalesAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual ActionTypeLookup ActionTypeLookup { get; set; }
    public virtual Campaign Campaign { get; set; }
    public virtual MarketingLetter MarketingLetter { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contact { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetUsers AspNetUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetUsers AspNetUsersEditedBy { get; set; }
}
}
```

And the Contact model

```
namespace SalesTracker.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Contact
{
    public Contact()
    {
        this.Activity = new HashSet<Activity>();
    }

    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime VerifiedDate { get; set; }
    public string VerifiedBy { get; set; }
    public int VerificationStatus { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime EditDate { get; set; }
    public string EditedBy { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public virtual SalesAccount SalesAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Activity> Activity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused with the purpose of `Clear()`. All it does is remove the reference between the parent and its children, it doesn't actually delete the entity. You will need to do something like the following to actually remove them:

```
activity.Contact.ToList().ForEach(c => db.Contact.DeleteObject(c));
```

Followed of course by your `db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: Makes sense.  When I implement this in the edit method above, Visual Studio claims that db (SalesTracker.Models.SalesEntities) does not contain a definition for 'Contact' even though I have a model for Contact and have no problem adding them.  I am using data first. Should I post my model classes as an edit above?  I am struggling with getting started with c# and MVC...

Comment: And when I use `activity.Contact.ToList().ForEach(c => db.tblContact.DeleteObject(c));` (there is a definition for tblContact as opposed to Contact) then it says there is no definition for DeleteObject.  I feel like I am missing something basic here.